# Using EWS, how do I get a meeting room name if I have its email address?

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2010

I have a list of meeting room email addresses and I would like to get their names. How do I do that using EWS and a 2010 exchange server. The server does not seem to have SP1 though, so I cannot use ExchanceService.ResolveName. If I do, I get the message `Method ResolveName is only valid for Exchange Server version Exchange2010_SP1 or later.`

UPDATE:

Actually, I am using https://outlook.office365.com, so I am not too sure why I am getting the above error message when I try to use the ResolveName method.

UPDATE 2:

In fact, yes, it is possible to use ResolveName on office365. I was just passing the wrong server version when instanciating ExchangeSercice. I was passing ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010, but it is also possible to use ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP1, ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP2, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `ResolveName` operation like below, to get the meeting room name:

```
    EmailAddressCollection roomLists = service.GetRoomLists();
    foreach (EmailAddress email in roomLists)
    {
        EmailAddress roomList = email.Address;
        PropertySet props = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties);
        NameResolutionCollection nrCol = service.ResolveName(email.Address, ResolveNameSearchLocation.DirectoryOnly, true, props);
        foreach (NameResolution nr in nrCol)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(nr.Contact.DisplayName);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! I had already resolved my problem, but it is good to have your code sample for other people who are looking for an answer on how to get a name knowing the email address.